# Delphi update source list for autocomplete

Tags: delphi, autocomplete

I am using IAutoComplete2 for updating a text box.  This is the code I'm using to create the IAutoComplete2:

```
lstSource:= TStringList.Create;
lstSource.LoadFromFile('source.txt');
FAutoSource  := CreateComObject(CLSID_AutoComplete) as IAutoComplete2;
FStringsSource := TEnumString.Create(lstSource) as IUnknown;
OleCheck(FAutoSource.SetOptions(ACO_AUTOAPPEND));
OleCheck(FAutoSource.Init(txtText.Handle, FStringsSource, nil, nil));
```

This is working fine, but I need to update the source list if the user types in something that isn't already in the list.  I am adding the new string to lstSource; how do I then update FStringsSource?

Nimusi

Comment: `TEnumString` has a reference to `lstSource`, so it can already see the new strings you add to it. If you are adding the strings to the end of the list, `FStringsSource.Next()` should see them automatically the next time it is called by the Edit control. Otherwise, try calling `FStringsSource.Reset()` to reset the enumeration back to the beginning of the list each time you modify it. If that still does not work, you may have to re-`Init()` the Edit control

Comment: Thanks @Remy. Following your suggestion I've been experimenting with this.

The solution seems to be to recreate the FAutoSource and FstringsSource objects and then re-Init FAutoSource.